# How to set onmousedown event for dynamically created div in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, onmousedown

I have a (Javascript) tool which dynamically creates a div whenever the user clicks on the screen.

```
_newDiv = document.createElement('div');
```

Now, after I've created `_newDiv`, I want to assign a `onmousedown` event to it.

```
_newDiv.onmousedown = function(event) { onNewDivMouseDown(event); };
```

This works perfectly in Firefox, but doesn't work in IE 8. Is there any hack I can use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!

It turns out that due to the fact that the dynamically created div was made transparent using progid:DXImageTransform, IE didn't capture the onmousedown event for said div. The problem was solved by inserting

```
background-image:url(/none)
```

in the div's stylesheet. For some reason it works even if a non-existing image is inserted, so I used that.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to IE9, the `event` object was not passed to the handler. Instead, it's a global variable. The traditional idiom therefore is:

```
function handler(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  // ...
}
```

So in your case:

```
_newDiv.onmousedown = function(event) {
    onNewDivMouseDown(event || window.event);
};
```

Comment: Problem is, even the onNewDivMouseDown function doesn't get called. I tried putting alert('!') instead of onNewDivMouseDown and it still doesn't work. I set if (!event) {event = window.event;} earlier in the code.

Comment: *later in the code (inside the onNewDivMouseDown function), not earlier :)

Comment: Perhaps I could help if I could see what you do with "_newDiv" - how do you add it to the DOM?  What does the rest of the page look like? Can you reproduce the issue with a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: `_newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        _newDiv.className = 'square'
        _newDiv.style.borderColor = #FF0000;
        _newDiv.style.left = '10 px';
        _newDiv.style.top  = '50 px';
    _newContainer = document.getElementById('newContainer');
        _newContainer.appendChild(_newDiv);...
    
    _newDiv.onmousedown = function(event) { onNewDivMouseDown(event); };`
    
Hope that this clears up the issue. It's working perfectly fine in Firefox, so I'm guessing it's some sort of an IE quirk.

Comment: Does the element even show up on the page with IE?  One thing that may be a problem is that CSS pixel measurements shouldn't have a space between the numeric value and the unit suffix; so, "10px", not "10 px". Do you see any errors in the IE8 developer console?

Comment: Yes, it shows up. It's just that I cannot assign any events to it. CSS is fine, I pasted '10 px' as an example. No errors in the console...

Comment: Alright, I've narrowed down the error to the onmousedown event. onmouseup and onmousemove work perfectly fine, but onmousedown is impossible to set in IE for some reason. Very strange...

Comment: Problem solved (look below)! It turns out that the problem was caused by the progid:DXImageTransform filter I used to make the div's background transparent.